# Execute SQL Server query using content read from Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I'm using the following code to read content from a spreadsheet then populate a gridview with the contents.

Instead of populating the gridview with the contents of the spreadsheet, I'd like to read each line of the spreadsheet and run a SQL Server query on the value of each line. I'd like to populate the gridview with the resulting data from these queries.

I'm having issues figuring out how to read the excel file line by line then inserting these values into a query. Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

```
//Read Data from First Sheet
connExcel.Open();
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT sku From [" + SheetName + "]";
oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
oda.Fill(dt);
connExcel.Close();

//Bind Data to GridView
GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: What exact "issues" are you having?

Comment: Issues finding a legitimate example that explains how to do this.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do? With the second query, do you mean you're trying to do an insert with the data or what?

Comment: No, I'm trying to loop through the first column of a spreadsheet and query the contents of each cell. The results would fill the repeater. So each line in the spreadsheet would have a corresponding line in the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft Excel Interop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

It's not difficult, just google it.

Comment: @66Mhz Don't forget to mark my answer as Accepted if it suits you. It will help others.